# Leaflet geojson search error(cannot read property 'lat' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, search, leaflet

In a leaflet map, I am adding a search function. based on attribute 'Clean_Feature_Name' in a geojson file with polygon coordinates. 
However, it does not search and just show below error message. It seems it does not search based on propertyName. Can please someone help?

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
at T.getCenter (leaflet.js:5)
at e._searchInLayer (leaflet-search.min.js:17)
at leaflet-search.min.js:17
at eachLayer (leaflet.js:5)
at e._recordsFromLayer (leaflet-search.min.js:17)
at e._fillRecordsCache (leaflet-search.min.js:17)
at leaflet-search.min.js:17
```

My geojson Data

```
var Mars = 
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
  {
   "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[[-68.42836570739746, 74.97826194763184], [-68.86942863464355, 74.8109302520752], [-69.42859840393066, 74.8525562286377], [-75.43949317932129, 76.16095542907715], [-75.46052360534668, 76.43600654602051], [-75.25974464416504, 77.1826000213623], [-75.18795585632324, 78.65801429748535], [-75.20999717712402, 78.6591625213623], [-74.92653465270996, 78.78381538391113], [-66.64877128601074, 77.87516212463379], [-66.60500526428223, 77.76282691955566], [-68.42836570739746, 74.97826194763184]]]
  },
  "properties": {
    "Feature_ID": 4,
    "Clean_Feature_Name": "Abalos Colles",
      }
 }
 ]
}

for(var i in Mars.features)
    Mars.features[i].properties.color = getColor(Mars.features[i].properties.number_of_papers );
```

This is my code (pretty much same as this sample https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/examples/geojson-layer.html )

```
var data = Mars;

   var featuresLayer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
     style: function(feature) {
       return {color: feature.properties.color };
    },
    }

   map.addLayer(featuresLayer);
     var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
      layer: featuresLayer,
      propertyName: 'Clean_Feature_Name',
      }
     });

  map.addControl( searchControl );  //inizialize search control
```

Comment: I suggest you read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, trying it with an unminified verson of leaflet may give you a less cryptic error message and help you track down the error.

Comment: Found an answer - the data size is the problem. If the data is too big, the plugin does not work with the error message. My data exceeds 20mb and it worked with small amount of data.